# ubuntu bower command, Error: EACCES, permission denied '.../insight-bower.json'

Tags: ubuntu, bower

I can't run bower command as my user, which gives me below error when run bower:

> Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/***/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json'
>   You don't have access to this file.

```
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:286:15)
at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:26)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:20:44)
at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:37:34)
at ensureInsight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/analytics.js:25:19)
at Object.setup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/analytics.js:41:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:72:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

but when i run bower as root, it works fine.

Whats the wrong? Its works fine before, but since i did the below command it goes wrong.

```
sudo bower cache clean --allow-root
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was the owner of file.
Because owner of file '/home/***/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json' was root, I just can run bower with sudo and --allow-root.

So the issue easily solved by changing the owner to myself, as below:

```
sudo chown bobsilon .config/configstore/insight-bower.json
```